# Can 'for' loops contain two variables and use console.log

Tags: javascript

I finally passed a repl.it exercise on 'for' loops but the accepted solution and model solution both seem incorrect to me. I have 2 specific questions about the solutions and have included the code for both solutions for clarity. Here are the instructions I tried my best to follow:

- In this exercise write your own for loop.
- It should loop 10 times.
- You are given a variable called: `count`.
- For each loop reassign `count` to the current value of `count + 1`.

I used `console.log(count)` within my loop whereas the model solution used `count++`. (2) Was it completely incorrect to use `console.log` or is it still correct but not as accurate? I used `console.log` because i was told to use it in the 1st exercise and this one contained very similar requirements. Last, (3) why did the model solution call its variable i when the instructions said the given variable was called count? Doesn't this effectively give the loop two variables? For reference, the first loop solution is my passing answer and the second solution is the model answer.

```
for (let count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
    console.log(count)
} 

for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
    count++;
```

Comment: You have no access to `count` outside your loop due to `let count` being block scoped. Try another log after the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions don't say that you should initialize `count`, it says that you're given the variable. That means that it should start with the existing value, which might not be `0`, and you should increment it 10 times with the loop.

That's what their solution does. It uses a different variable to keep track of how many times it iterates, to avoid losing the original value of `count`.

However, since your solution was accepted, I guess they weren't really enforcing this.

In a real application, you might do something like this if you're using the `count` variable to calculate a total over multiple loops. Or you might increment the counter conditionally within the loop, e.g. counting the number of times you find something in an array. There are many situations where the variable you're incrementing is not the same as the one used to control the loop iterations.

Comment: Sorry my error, the preset code in the exercise had already initialized count to 0. I didn’t realize that I didn’t need to initialize count so thank you for that. Based on that, I changed the loop to:

for(count; count < 10; count++ ){
     }
I just removed the unnecessary initialization. Would this be better? Also, do you mean this single loop itself could potentially lose the original value of count? Or is that only a risk if using count in multiple loops? Your detailed explanation helped a lot. Thanks. I upvoted your answer but I've too little Reputation for it to count publicly.

Comment: It's only an issue if you need to keep adding to a previous `count`, to compute a grand total across multiple iterations.

Comment: Accepting the answer gives more rep than upvoting.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Also I upvoted and accepted the answer. Your check mark is green on my end so I'm not sure why the acceptance isn't showing unless that also depends upon Reputation to be public. Thanks a lot for your help!